# Changing a Delphi/Oracle application from 2-tier to 3-tier

Tags: oracle, delphi, architecture, components, 3-tier

In my company they are finally (about time...) considering to convert one of our best selling apps from a 2-tier to 3-tier architecture, both on logical (Presentation, Business and Data layers) as well as physical level. Probably we will go for either a Delphi-Delphi-Oracle or a Delphi-Java-Oracle approach for the change.

This is a relatively old and large app that has been created and modified for a long time before I began working there. Refactoring, except for when something had to be changed, was usually never considered. Also, business logic is present in both of the actual tiers... sigh.

The physical change does not bother me much but the logical change will be kind of a passage through Hell. In order to smooth it as much as possible I would like to investigate about which Delphi components suit better for a 3-tier model.

¿Which alternatives would you consider to use?

Comment: What are the driving factors for this plan? For example, support for other databases or other front-ends (mobile, web, .net) or cloud deployment? This would give a clearer picture, for example for the choice between Delphi and/or Java in the middle tier.

Comment: I asked basically the same thing:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431149/which-delphi-technology-to-use

Comment: @mjustin, there are two main reasons for our client: they want to be able to deploy to other databases if needed and they also want to be able to scale rapidly since they are growing 2 digits each year. Thx for your comment :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've recently converted our 2 tier Delphi app to 3 tier using RemObjects DataAbstract. While the initial learning curve was quite steep, we are absolutely delighted with the results.

DataAbstract lets you forget about the underlying nuts and bolts of database and network connectivity and concentrate on the business logic. It allows you to create an abstract service layer that provides your server clients with a nice API. Using this API we connect to the server using both a Delphi and a Delphi Prism ASP.NET client.

Comment: What were the hardest problems/questions you found when learning how to use RemObjects DataAbstract?

Comment: I think the hardest part is getting your head around the way the DA framework operates. I'd say the documentation is less than fantastic, but they do answer most questions quickly and informatively.

DA allows you to create a 3 tier system with virtually no coding. Just create a schema and that's it. Unfortunately, the way we do things prevented us from doing this, but we still found the architecture flexible enough to allow us to do what we needed quickly and fairly easily.

The thought of going back to a 2 tier system now fills me with dread... good luck :)

Answer (score 5):

Another good n-tier framework library is kbmMW from components4developers: http://components4developers.com/

Answer (score 3):

I've found RemObjects pretty usable. They have also DataAbstract built top on it, but I haven't used it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever considered DataSnap XE?